# IIS Dockerfile: APPCMD failed with error code 4312

Tags: docker, iis, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I have a docker file with some variables and CMD instruction. And it do not work if I'll add CMD and variables. Simplified example below.

Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019
ENV MY_SUPER_VARIABLE="Hello world!"
CMD ["powershell", "echo", "Hello!"]
```

docker info:

```
Client:
Debug Mode: false

Server:
Containers: 46
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 46
Images: 65
Server Version: 19.03.2
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: process
Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
Operating System: Windows Server 2019 Standard Evaluation Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.615)
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.906GiB
Name: WIN-P1U2Q5DO49C
ID: 4BOF:LAK4:XOTP:2FNA:3OBR:YDIU:LFWW:3MZ3:N6R4:ZIAC:QK3X:VDSX
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode: true
File Descriptors: -1
Goroutines: 41
System Time: 2019-10-01T05:15:37.0250428-07:00
EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

Commands:

```
docker build -t oracle_db .
docker run -it oracle_db
```

Result:

```
 Service 'w3svc' has been stopped

APPCMD failed with error code 4312

Failed to update IIS configuration
```

If I remove ENV or CMD instruction, everything will work fine, but I need both instructions.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/iis-docker/issues/154

Answer (score 3):

The IIS base image already has an entrypoint defined. Your call to `CMD` is not running powershell during the build, it is adding additional parameters to the existing `ENTRYPOINT`. If you are trying to run something as part of the build, you need to use `RUN` and not `CMD`